# Istio gives 404 NR response when it should be giving 200

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

### Related issue

[Istio envoy is dropping requests with Host header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188518/istio-envoy-is-dropping-requests-with-host-header)

The above issue is the only one that's even remotely similar to my issue. However, the Host in my header is `service-b.myns.svc.cluster.local` and I don't see why that should be a problem.

### The situation

I've got a namespace with many `Deployment`s and `Service`s. And for each `Service` I've also defined a `VirtualService`. Example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  labels:
    app: service-b
  name: service-b
  namespace: myns
spec:
  gateways:
  - myns.myns.svc.cluster.local
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /.well-known
    - uri:
        prefix: /robots.txt
    - uri:
        prefix: /apple-app-site-association
    - uri:
        prefix: /favicon.ico
    - uri:
        prefix: /content/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: service-b.myns.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

### The problem

I have another service, call it `service-a` that should be able to retrieve `/.well-known`, `robots.txt`, `/content/header`, `/content/footer` etc. I'm assuming that, because I've defined a route for these paths to lead directly to `service-b`, they should be retrievable by `service-a`. However, the logs say this:

```
[2019-02-22T01:07:54.557Z] "GET /content/headerHTTP/1.1" 404 NR 0 0 0 - "-" "curl/7.52.1" "789b3b81-9f61-43c3-b01a-b66d35c1d635" "service-b" "-" - - 10.x.x.x:80 10.y.y.y:47526
```

### Question #1

Per the [Envoy docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/access_log), `NR` means no route. Have I not defined a route in my `VirtualService`?

### Question #2

I can get a `200` response for each of those paths if I just plug them in to the URL bar in my browser (ie. `<istio-ingressgateway-ip-address>/robots.txt`). Why?

### Some proggress

I've narrowed down the issue to the istio proxy on the pod for `service-a`. I did this by removing the istio-proxy sidecars one at a time. There are two cases in which I get successfull `200`s from `service-a`:

```
[SVCA][ISTIOPROXY] ---> X [ISTIOPROXY][SVCB]  # Does not work
[SVCA][ISTIOPROXY] ---> X             [SVCB]  # Does not work
[SVCA]             ---> ✓             [SVCB]  # Does work
[SVCA]             ---> ✓ [ISTIOPROXY][SVCB]  # Does work
```

Comment: `istioctl proxy-config endpoint service-a` reveals that it has a `HEALTHY outbound|80||service-b.myns.svc.cluster.local` endpoint in the configuration.

EDIT: Actually two of them because `service-b` has two pods.

Comment: You have gateways: specified. Do you *really* have a gateway set up in this way? That might also explain why this is routing externally via Istio Gateway... What happens if you remove that gateways: declaration?

Comment: Thanks @PaulAnnetts, the trouble is that the default gateway is `mesh` and I get this error: `wildcard host * is not allowed for virtual services bound to the mesh gateway`.  --  Normally it would not be a `*` for hosts, however this is a test cluster that I have not set up with any DNS, so I have to hit it with an IP Address... well it looks like I can just put the IP Address there and delete the `gateways` block. -- But it still doesn't work... actually it looks like my `RDS` is `STALE` on all my pods except the `istio-ingressgateway` (`istioctl proxy-status`)

Comment: FWIW... I tweaked a `ServiceEntry` and it started working. Then I tried to reproduce the issue but I was unable to get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You don't configured default route.

Example with default route:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  labels:
    app: service-b
  name: service-b
  namespace: myns
spec:
  gateways:
  - myns.myns.svc.cluster.local
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /.well-known
    - uri:
        prefix: /robots.txt
    - uri:
        prefix: /apple-app-site-association
    - uri:
        prefix: /favicon.ico
    - uri:
        prefix: /content/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: service-a.myns.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: service-b.myns.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```